# Look for existing entry in database before trying to insert

Tags: python, database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am currently working with Access 2013. I have built a database that revolves around applicants submitting for a Job. The database is set up so that a person can apply for many different jobs, when the same person applies for a job through our website (uses JotForms) it automatically updates the database.

I have a Python script pulling the applicants submission information from an email which updates the database. The problem that I am running into is that within the database I have the applicants primary email set to "no duplicates", thus not allowing the same person to apply for many different jobs as the Python script is trying to create a new record within the database causing an error.

Within my Access form (VBA) or in Python what do I need to write to tell my database if the primary emails are the same only create a new record within the position applied for table that is related to the persons primary email?

Tables:

```
tblPerson_Information   tblPosition_Applied_for
Personal_ID  (PK)       Position_ID
First_Name              Position_Personal_ID (FK)
Last_Name               Date_of_Submission
Clearance_Type
Primary_Phone
Primary_email
Education_Level
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply look up the email address in the [tblPerson_Information] table:

```python
primary_email = 'gord@example.com'  # test data

crsr = conn.cursor()    
sql = """\
SELECT Personal_ID FROM tblPerson_Information WHERE Primary_email=?
"""
crsr.execute(sql, (primary_email))
row = crsr.fetchone()
if row is not None:
    personal_id = row[0]
    print('Email found: tblPerson_Information.Personal_ID = {0}'.format(personal_id))
else:
    print('Email not found in tblPerson_Information')
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this inside my script and see how it works.